# Azure ServiceBus Namespace - Delete from old subscription and create in new subscription

Tags: azure, servicebus

What is the length of time it takes for a deleted Service Bus namespace to become available for another subscription.

I've deleted one and would like to recreate it in a different Subscription, however this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of the operation is undefined. The documentation of the [Delete Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj856296.aspx) REST API operation states:

> This does not mean that the namespace is completely deleted at the return of the API call. It means that it is marked for deletion.

This forum thread ("[Re-use namespace (azure)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/8146b537-3860-41be-8750-8b4a0ffab37a/reuse-namespace-azure)") contains information that the namespace name should be available in a few minutes for use in the same subscription, and that it is reserved for 7 days during which it can only be recreated in the original subscription. In case you can't wait, you may reach out to Azure support.

The [Namespace Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj873988.aspx) REST API operation can be used to retrieve the namespace status (including "Deleting"). See also the [NamespaceDescription.Status Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.management.namespacedescription.status.aspx) in the Service Bus Class Library for .NET.

The [Check Namespace Availability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj870968.aspx) REST API operation can be used to check when the namespace name becomes available after a delete request.

Answer (score 0):

4 hours:

> When you delete a namespace from a subscription, wait for 4 hours
> before recreating it with the same name in another subscription.
> Otherwise, you may receive the following error message: Namespace
> already exists.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-faq#why-am-i-not-able-to-create-a-namespace-after-deleting-it-from-another-subscription--

In fact, as of now it actually specifies it in the error:

```
The namespace name is previously used in another subscription and has been deleted less than 4 hours.
```